# macOS blocking serial I/O

Tags: macos, serial-port, blocking

I'm writing a tool as part of a test suite, which needs to talk over a serial port to some hardware so that the code being tested sees the environment change.

So, I do this:

```
open("/dev/tty.usbmodem14141", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
```

only it hangs there. If I replace that call with

```
open("/dev/tty.usbmodem14141", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
```

then it works -- but I would prefer not to have to fiddle with select() and friends, or write a busy-loop poll, just so I can read from the serial port; that's what blocking I/O is for.

Do I need to do anything special for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

When you have opened the serial terminal in nonblocking mode, you can then clear the file status flag to perform I/O in blocking mode.

To clear the nonblocking status flag you can use [fcntl()](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/fcntl.2.html), e.g.:

```
int flags;

flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
flags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags);
```

Since the Linux version of F_SETFL can change only the O_APPEND, O_ASYNC, O_DIRECT, O_NOATIME, and O_NONBLOCK flags, common practice is to simplify the code down to just

```
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
```

(Yes, the single-liner does not have the same degree of portability as advocated in [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237).)

Comment: I should have thought of that :) unfortunately though, it also doesn't work; rather than hanging on the open() call, it now hangs on the first write().

Comment: *"it now hangs on the first write()"* -- Then that confirms your program is using blocking I/O, i.e. my answer is a viable solution.  You now have progressed to a second and different issue, but you have posted no code relating to it or any description of your setup.  For a WAG flow control and/or modem control is probably involved.

Comment: The program works just fine, unmodified, with the exact same hardware (an Arduino plugged into a USB port) on Linux. It does not work the same way on macOS, not even when I open in nonblocking mode and then move to nonblocking mode with fcntl(). i.e., it is not actually a separate issue, and it does not solve the problem, it just moves it around... also, I *have* posted all the relevant bits; a simple "main()" that does nothing but call the above "open()" reproduces the issue for me.

Comment: *"The program works just fine, unmodified, with the exact same hardware (an Arduino plugged into a USB port) on Linux."* -- That simply proves that you do not have a portable program, which is easy to do with serial port code. Now you're providing new information in a comment that tries to expand the scope of the original question. I answered the original question/problem as posted. It's your responsibility to ask the question that accurately describes the problem. That's how this site operates; you should know that.